# Picture Tag/element display issues

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to implement the new HTML5 picture tag into my code, however, when following W3C's guide on the element, it only shows the fallback image, not the images its supposed to when resizing.

I'm unsure as to whether or not the picture container requires CSS styling to ensure the image switches when resizing.

Any help would be appriciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<div id="header">
</div> <!-- end of header -->

<nav>
<ul>

<li id="HomeButton">
<a href="index.html"><img id="HomeText" src="Images/Icons/HomeText.png" /></a>
</li>

<li id="WhatsWhatButton">
<a href="whatswhat.html"><img id="WhatsWhatText" src="Images/Icons/WhatsWhatText.png" /></a>
</li>

<li id="FoodFromPlantsButton">
<a href="foodfromplants.html"><img id="FoodFromPlantsText" src="Images/Icons/FoodFromPlantsText.png" /></a>
</li>

<li id="HowPlantsGrowButton">
<div id="HowPlantsGrowText">
<a href="howplantsgrow.html"><img src="Images/Icons/HowPlantsGrowText.png" /></a>
</div>
<div id="HowPlantsGrowIcon"></div>
</li>

<li id="PlantGameButton">
<a href="plantGame.html"><img id="PlantGameText" src="Images/Icons/PlantGameText.png" /></a>
</li>
</ul>
</nav> <!-- end of nav -->

<div id="page">
<div id="content">

<img class="title" src="Images/Icons/FoodFromPlantsTitle.png" width="250" height="100"/>

<picture alt="angry pirate">
   <source src=Images/Icons/HomeIcon.png media="min-width:800px">
   <source src=Images/Icons/FoodFromPlantsIcon.png media="min-width:480px">
   <source src=Images/Icons/PlantGame.png>
      <!-- fallback for browsers without support -->
      <img src=Images/Icons/WhatsWhatIcon.png alt="angry pirate">
</picture>

</div> <!-- end of content -->
</div> <!-- end of page -->

<footer>
</footer> <!-- end of footer -->
</div>  <!-- end of container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does picture tag even official yet?

Comment: http://responsiveimages.org/demos/

Some working examples

Comment: Would you add a link to the guide you're using?

Comment: http://picture.responsiveimages.org/

Unofficial draft for my guide use

Comment: Looks like that demos page is using a JavaScript polyfill.

Comment: Would you say its a custom polyfill or would Modernizr possible allow support for none native supporting browsers?

Comment: At a glance it looks custom, but I've not analysed it.

Comment: @MattMeadows Note on the doc: "This specification is under active development and changing frequently." This seems far from being a W3C guide, so keep in mind that anything you know/learn about this might suddenly change, a lot :) Sorry I can't give you more tangible info. If you only see the fallback image, the browser you're using might not support this tag yet.

Comment: Ok, many thanks for the comments made.

It strongly appears that it isn't fully supoorted and custom polyfills are required to make it act as if it were to work.

Comment: Yup, there's a link to some reference implementations in that doc that lead to https://github.com/Wilto/draft-prop/wiki/Current-users,-polyfills,-prototypes,-and-implementations . I think the one used in the demo is one of those.

Answer (score 0):

The `<picture>` element is most likely not supported yet in the browsers you are trying it in. It is, however, on its way in the latest builds of both Chrome, Firefox and WebKit/Safari.

Until it's supported, use the official polyfill from http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/.
Note that it requires some funky markup to work in IE, and does not show an image at all if JS fails or is turned off (no way around that, sadly).